# Is "news" singular?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Is "news" singular?

How do I say it: "The news is nice" or it should be "The news are nice" 
?

I've read that it's a singular and plural noun by default. Also If it's plural is there a way to refer to only one "NEWS"?

Answer (score 2):

***News*** is treated as grammatically singular (or at least I've never encountered an exception where it's treated as a plural); "only one 'news'" is generally referred to as "a news story" or "a news item".

Comment: I'm told that my grandmother (or maybe my great grandmother - I didn't know either of them) used to use "news" as plural. But then English wasn't her native language.